# Headphones/splitter issue: Sounds okay in the right ear, but it is extremely low in the left ear

Tags: audio, headphones, splitter

I have some headphones which work just fine on my PlayStation, computer, etc.

However, when I plug them into my splitter (and another device was connected), only half of it was working.

It sounds okay in the right ear, but it is extremely low in the left ear.

The issue probably doesn't come from the splitter because it sounded exactly the same with another splitter.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it ?

Ps : I have a Hama audio splitter, and a Hyper X Cloud alpha

Comment: Please edit your question to add details on the headphone and the splitter. What brand are they? What model?

Comment: I would imagine that one channel it is being drained through to another device. Moral of this story is don't use splitters - they are jink.

Comment: I've just edited my original message

Comment: Are you using the included TRRS - 2xTRS splitter to split the microphone and headphone jacks and plugging the headphone jack (two green rings around the jack) into the splitter? Or are you plugging the TRRS (three black rings) plug into the splitter directly?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I plug my headphones directly into the splitter, I don't add anything else